# Unable to set value of dropdown on page load

Tags: javascript, infopath, custom-list

I am using SharePoint 2013 online and I have created a form for my list using Infopath 2013. It has a combination of text fields and dropdowns.

I am able to set the default value of text field using like

`$('input[originalid="V1_I1_T6"]').val('hello');`

but not the dropdown like

`$('select[originalid="V1_I1_D16"]').val('45');`

What am I missing?

[image]

Comment: What is this originalid="V1_I1_D16"

Comment: It is one of the attributes

Answer (score 0):

Check this.Make sure Jquery is referenced

```
$('select[originalid=V1_I1_T6]').val("45");
```

Check this fiddler link also which I created.
https://jsfiddle.net/tL5k6w22/

Comment: Please update your first answer instead of posting multiple very similar answers!

Comment: I knows its working in the jsfiddle. But it does not work with form build in Infopath.

Answer (score 0):

The complete jquery code is :

```
DropDownList.SetValueOfControl($('#ctl00_ctl45_g_aa5a291c_b931_4c0f_b477_f57a9cf522f2_FormControl0_V1_I1_D2')[0],lookupVal );


$("select[originalid='V1_I1_D2']").val(lookupVal).change();
```

Comment: I have a strong belief there is a possibility that this code won't compile :)

Answer (score 0):

**make sure to call focus before setting value,**

```
$('select[id=V1_I1_T6]').focus();

$('select[id=V1_I1_T6]').val('hello');
```